# How to pass the current activity to be Injected to an Object in Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Let's say I have a class `A` defined like this:

```
class A {

    Activity c;

    public A(Activity c) {
        this.c = c;
        // do something
    }

    public void dosomething() { }

}
```

And I have an Activity defined like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject A myObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myObject.dosomething();
    }
}
```

How can I provide the current activity to my object?

Answer (score 7):

You have to make the activity available to the component responsible for constructing `myObject`. One way to do that is to create an `ActivityScope`:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}
```

Within this scope, you create a component with an `inject()` method for injecting the Activity's fields.

Note that you can add a dependency on a wider-scoped component if you want that component's object graph available in your `MyActivityComponent`. Here, I made it depend on a class named `ApplicationComponent`.

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(
        dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}, 
        modules = { MyActivityModule.class}
)
public interface MyActivityComponent {

    void inject(MyActivity myActivity);

}
```

The component has a module that provides the `MyActivity` instance.

```
@Module
public class MyActivityModule {

    private final MyActivity myActivity;

    public MyActivityModule(MyActivity myActivity) {
        this.myActivity = myActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    MyActivity provideActivity() {
        return myActivity;
    }

}
```

In your activity's `onCreate()`, you can now give `this` to the module, which makes it available within the `ActivityScope`.

```
//Inside your activity's onCreate:
DaggerMyActivityComponent.builder()
        .myActivityModule(new MyActivityModule(this))
        .build()
        .inject(this);
```

**EDIT**
In response to your question, you need to annotate the constructor in `A` with `@Inject`. This will give Dagger a way to create an instance of it. If that's not possible, you could add a provider method in the module, but it's a bit more work:

```
//Don't do this if you can annotate the constructor with @Inject.
@Provides
A provideA(MyActivity myActivity) {
    return new A(myActivity);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but i got more errors : 
Error:(22, 10) error: me.ha.colorselector.MainActivity cannot be provided without an @ Inject constructor or from an @ Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.

Comment: @Oussaki Ah, I overlooked that. I edited my answer for you.